# draw control - position of the circle and rectangle buttons

Tags: leaflet.draw

the leaflet-draw draw control has the "draw circle" button below the "draw rectangle".  Can I switch them so that the "Draw Circle" is above the "Draw Rectangle"?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to use a local version of leaflet-draw and change the source code around a bit, try moving the circle above the other `options` in [this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/master/src/draw/DrawToolbar.js) file.

Comment: OK - that was more work than I hoped for, so we'll leave it as is.  Thank you for the quick response